# Does CGImageGetDataProvider depend on type of image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, ipad

I used `CGImageGetDataProvider` and `CGDataProviderCopyData` and then get a pointer to the data.  The first image I tested was a bmp and this method worked great.  However, I changed my image to a JPG because I had read something about the Data Provider possibly being relative to the type of image.  The length of that data returned indicates that it is 4 when it should be some large number representing the rows and columns of the image.

What I need is  I can ask for the Data Provider to be for a bitmap so I can walk through the data uncompressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you get out of the data provider will be the data that went into creating the image.  For instance, if the image was created using `CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider`, it would be JPEG data.  If you want bitmap data, you will need to make a bitmap, perhaps using `CGBitmapContextCreate`, and draw the image into the bitmap.

Comment: CGBitmapContextCreeate have so many step. is there any direct method to convert JPEG data in to bitmap.It would be great if I can get the difference between  Bitmap and JPEG data.

Comment: No, I don't think there is any easier way.